# deserialize json array of object c# RIOT API [NOT WORKING]

Tags: json, rest, object, deserialization, json-deserialization

i've recently started to start on a new small project, but have come across some issues.. I'm not really sure why it's not working honestly.

```
public partial class MatchlistDto
{
    public List<MatchHistory> matchhistory { get; set; }
}

public partial class MatchHistory
{
    [JsonProperty("platformId")]
    public string platformId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("gameId")]
    public long gameId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("champion")]
    public int champion { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("queue")]
    public int queue { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("season")]
    public int season { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("timestamp")]
    public long timestamp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("role")]
    public string role { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lane")]
    public string lane { get; set; }


}
public partial  class SummonerV4
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string accountId { get; set; }
    public string puuid { get; set; }
    public string profileIconId { get; set; }
    public string revisionDate { get; set; }
    public string summonerLevel { get; set; }
}
```

---

Code from Controller.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> DisplayAccount(string Region, string User)
    {
        string ApiKey = "TottalyAnApiKey";
   

        SummonerV4 UserInfo = new SummonerV4();

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("https://" + Region + ".api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/"+ User +"?api_key="+ ApiKey);

            if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var apiResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;  //First part is to get AccountInformation from user. e.g AccountID.
                UserInfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SummonerV4>(apiResponse);

                HttpResponseMessage Res2 = await client.GetAsync("https://" + Region + ".api.riotgames.com" + "/lol/match/v4/matchlists/by-account/" + User + "?api_key=" + ApiKey); //Second part is to collect the Match History from user.

                if (Res2.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var PersonalResponse2 = Res2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                   List<MatchlistDto> matchHistoryList =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MatchlistDto>>(PersonalResponse2);

                }

            }
        }
        return View(UserInfo);
    }
```

So whats going on is that, i do get the correct response from RiotGames API but i can't really deserialize it correctly. Please check images. My wish is to store the data in a list or array.

Here you can see all the objects from the response

[image]

And here the error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A couple problems:

### 1: MatchlistDto matchhistory field is misnamed

It should look like this:

```cs
public partial class MatchlistDto
{
    public List<MatchHistory> matches { get; set; }
}
```

Or like this:

```cs
public partial class MatchlistDto
{
    [JsonProperty("matches")]
    public List<MatchHistory> matchhistory { get; set; }
}
```

### 2: API returns a MatchlistDto, not a List

Should write this:

```cs
MatchlistDto matchHistoryList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MatchlistDto>(PersonalResponse2);
```